# Formula or Macro to divide long list (multiple columns) into separate lists based on criteria in one column

Tags: excel, split, criteria

I have a log list of data with the first two columns as potential identifiers, as shown in shortened form in the image at Flickr (noobie - can't post pictures):

http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7036/7114053281_30bf57300d.jpg

I have already sorted based on value Column B. I would like to be able to split this long set of data into separated lists of the four columns, with a single list containing one "Spot ID", like this:

http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8160/6967974902_7f84b57e46.jpg

Column A "Frame #" is not critical, but I left it in since I wondered if it could be used to make the macro easier to run.

I have to process a lot of data like this, so I want to understand how I can modify the macro to send the separate lists to different sheets, rather than different columns, for instance.

In case you are wondering, the Frame # refers to a video micrograph frame, and the spot ID refers to a specific colloidal particle that was tracked. X Pos and Y Pos are X and Y coordinates, respectively.

Any help is much appreciated.

nan0guy

Comment: Definte "a lot of data like this".  And is this a one-time thing?

Comment: How many distinct "spot id" values in one dataset?

Comment: "A Lot" - GBs of visual data that is being tracked, producing hundreds of traces per data set. Regularly generating more data. This is a statistical mechanics phenomena (biased Brownian motion), so the more data, the better the understanding.

Comment: Number of distinct "Spot IDs" - varies from 10 - 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it uses a simple AUTOFILTER to get each row with the unique SPOT ID, the onlyh thing it doesn't do is keep the ... ... .... ... row in the middle, hopefully that's not actually critical.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitColumns()
Dim c As Range, wsNEW As Worksheet, NC As Long, LR As Long
Dim List As New Collection, Item As Variant

With ActiveSheet
    .AutoFilterMode = False       // turn autofilter off
    LR = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row        //count cells in A 

    On Error Resume Next        //on error, continue on next line
    For Each c In .Range("B:B").SpecialCells(xlConstants, xlNumbers) //Help here?
        //doing something to the values in column B (the Spot IDs)
        List.Add c.Value, CStr(c.Value)        //Make a list of values in column A in c
    Next c        //For-next loop
    On Error GoTo 0

    .Rows(1).AutoFilter        //turn autofilter on?
    Set wsNEW = Sheets.Add        //add a new sheet
    NC = 1        //counter for columns in new sheet

    For Each Item In List        //exactly, but where does Item come from?
        .Rows(1).AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:=Item //autofilter using Item as criteria
        .Range("B1:D" & LR).Copy wsNEW.Cells(1, NC)  //copy everything in the range to new column in new sheet
        NC = NC + 3        //iterate column by 3
    Next Item        // for-next loop

    .AutoFilterMode = False        // turn autofilter off
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully!! thanks. Editing comments in to help me understand it - feel free to correct me.

Comment: Earlier, the macro cycled through and created a "collection" of unique values, we use the variant "ITEM" later to cycle through each "item" in the LIST the collection method created.  Your comments indicate a perfect understanding of what is happening.

Comment: If you want to see all the options you have at your disposal using the SPECIALCELLS method, in a sheet press F5 and click the SPECIAL button in the lower right corner.  Special cells lets you isolate a range of cells based on specific characteristics.  In the macro, we search column B for all constants that are numbers, then cycle through them each adding them to the "LIST" collection. The collection method doesn't result in duplicates.